# Iterate through dictionaries jq - shell

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a JSON like this

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
     ......
     ......
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-60@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

I want to iterate through each dictionary in `images` array.
For that I wrote

```
declare -a images=($(cat Contents.json | jq ".images[]"))
for image in "${images[@]}"
do
    echo "image --$image"
done
```

I am expecting output that each dictionary is printing in an iteration. That is

```
image --{
  "size" : "29x29",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
  "scale" : "2x"
}
image --{
  "size" : "29x29",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "Icon-Small@3x.png",
  "scale" : "3x"
}
image --{
  "size" : "40x40",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "Icon-Spotlight-40@2x.png",
  "scale" : "2x"
}
```

Etc

But its iterating through each and every single elements in each dictionary like

```
image --{
image --"size":
image --"29x29",
image --"idiom":
image --"iphone",
image --"filename":
....
....
....
```

What is wrong with  my code

Comment: The problem seems to be with storing multiline elements in an array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with your code is that an array initialization in bash looks like this:

```
declare -a arr=(item1 item2 item3)
```

Items are separated by space or newline. You can also use:

```
declare -a arr(
    item1
    item2
    item3
)
```

However, the `jq` output in the example contains both spaces and newlines, that's why the reported behaviour is as expected.

---

Workaround:

I would get the keys first, pipe them to a read loop and then call `jq` for each item of the list:

```sh
jq -r '.images|keys[]' Contents.json | while read key ; do
    echo "image --$(jq ".images[$key]" Contents.json)"
done
```

You can also use this `jq` command if you don't care about pretty printing:

```
jq -r '.images[]|"image --" + tostring' Contents.json
```

---

To access a certain property of the subarray you can use:

```
jq -r '.images|keys[]' Contents.json | while read key ; do
    echo "image --$(jq ".images[$key].filename" Contents.json)"
done
```

The above node will print the filename property for each node for example.

However this can be expressed much simpler using `jq` only:

```
jq -r '.images[]|"image --" + .filename' Contents.json
```

Or even simpler:

```
jq '"image --\(.images[].filename)"' Contents.json
```

Comment: The code is working perfectly *image --* is used just for distinguishing new lines wile printing

Comment: One more doubt, how can I separate each keys from the imageDict

Comment: I tried 
jq -r '.images|keys[]' $contentsPath | while read key ; do
    imageDict=$(jq ".images[$key]" $contentsPath)
    echo "image --$imageDict"
    echo "filename --"$("$imageDict" | jq ".filename" )
done
but its not working @hek2ml

Comment: instead of printing whole elements how can I print specific value for key sy filename in the loop

Comment: +1 Working as expected :) a small side question. if we use like this(the while read method), is it reading from file each time or reading only once?

Comment: each time in the sense in each iteration

Comment: Each time. That's the drawback. I would use the `jq`-only solution I've suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99307/discussion-between-johnykutty-and-hek2mgl).

Comment: I also like reading only one, but my need is to read 2-3keys from the dictionary and process them. Anywyay this is working fine