# Perform average of values of a particular field inside a JSON using jq

Tags: json, bash, parsing, jq

I have the following JSON data.

```
{
   "meta":{
      "earliest_ts":1601425980,
      "latest_ts":1601482740,
      "interval":"minutes",
      "level":"cluster",
      "entity_id":"xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
      "stat_labels":[
         "status_code_classes_per_workspace_total"
      ],
      "entity_type":"workspace",
      "start_ts":"1601425980"
   },
   "stats":{
      "cluster":{
         "1601431620":{
            "3xx":2,
            "4xx":87,
            "5xx":31,
            "2xx":352
         },
         "1601472780":{
            "3xx":14,
            "4xx":296,
            "5xx":2,
            "2xx":3811
         },
         "1601479140":{
            "3xx":17,
            "4xx":397,
            "5xx":19,
            "2xx":4399
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I try to do the average of all the `"3xx"` fields.

Using `jq`, I manage to get the key for each of my cluster :

```
echo $data | jq -r '.stats.cluster|keys' | while read key; do 
  echo $key
done
```

Output :

```
[
"1601431620",
"1601472780",
"1601479140"
]
```

But when I try to go further I can't manage to further and to retrieve the data from each field.
I got some insperation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529156/iterate-through-dictionaries-jq-shell).

The code below doesn't work, but you get the idea :

```
 # total var will be used to calculate the average
 total=$(echo $data | jq ".stats.cluster" | jq length)

 # for each cluster ...
 echo $data | jq '.stats.cluster|keys' | while read key; do
    # ... we retrieve the value "3xx"
    i=$($data | jq '.stats.cluster.$key."3xx"')
    # ... that we add into a sum var
    sum=$(( sum + i ))
 done
 
 # we calculate the average
 avg=$(( $sum / $total ))
 echo "The average is $avg"
```

I can't path directly to the data in jq like `jq '.stats.cluster."1601431620"."3xx"` because the cluster are so many and change all the time.

The desired output with my example above would be `11` as `(2 + 14 + 17) / 3`, those number all coming from the `3xx`'s items field.

Comment: Note that `echo $data` introduces its own bugs. __Always__ quote your expansions: `echo "$data"`; see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the value directly from jq:

```
$ jq '[.stats.cluster[]["3xx"]] | add / length' <<< "$data"
11
```