# How can I check if a playbook is being used by any job template?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

We have an organization with several hundred job templates.

I essentially want to do some housekeeping and identify any unused playbooks in my repository.

Is there a way to get details about each job template (including playbook) so that I can `grep` for a specific playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way to get details about each job template (including playbook) so that I can grep for a specific playbook?*

The short answers is: yes, of course. The long answer is: someone has to create such task. To do so, one may getting familiar with the [Ansible Tower REST API](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html), in detail [Job Templates - List Job Templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates).

In example, a call to **List Job Templates**

```bash
curl --silent --user ${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD} https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/ --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" | jq .
```

would result into an output (example) of

```json
{
  "count": 29,
  "next": "/api/v2/job_templates/?page=2",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
200
```

`results` will contain the list of all Job Templates. For further processing one may look for the values of the key `playbook` in `--raw-output` only.

```bash
curl --silent --user ${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD} https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/ | jq --raw-output '.results[] | .playbook'
```

One can then just `grep` over the output.

**Further Q&A**

- [Schedule deletion of unused template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73319490/6771046)
- [Iterate through dictionaries in shell via `jq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34529271/6771046)